# Json add to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I have a big array. I must add this array to mysql. With an array I made json code...
How I can add to mysql array in json?

```
$pola=json_encode($_POST['pola']);
$sql="insert info formularze (nazwa, odbiorca, pola, strona) values ('$nazwa','$odbiorca','$pola',$strona)";
```

Ex. json:

```
[{"nazwa":"Imi\u0119","typ":"input","placeholder":"Podaj swoje imi\u0119"},{"nazwa":"Nazwisko","typ":"input","placeholder":"Podaj swoje nazwisko"},{"nazwa":"Wiadomo\u015b\u0107","typ":"textarea","placeholder":"Co chcesz ode mnie :)"},{"nazwa":"Czy masz 18 lat?","typ":"radio","opcje":"Tak\r\nNie"}]
```

I tried used: mysql_real_escape_string. This function added "\" etc. but didn't help.

I see that WordPress have records with json.

Comment: Don't. Normalise your data instead. If you wrap it up in JSON then you make it unsearchable.

Comment: its a bad practice to put json to database, may be better do some changes to db and store structured data?.. thing what you do is a bad bad practice (just a note)

Comment: anyway what type of mysql field do you use to store json?

Comment: It's problem, because I don't know, how much data user can add to mysql.

This query adds: form fields with his values. The user specifies the number of fields and their values. The most convenient way is to add the whole arrays.

Comment: Then for each field he enters make a new row in the database and add a parent ID so you know which ones belong together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use prepared statements to store this without any problem inside the database.
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Note:

As said in the comments it's a bit of bad practice to store json in database. May be you should restructure your database schema.

Answer (score 0):

first you try this function

```
   <?php

   $query = 'insert into formularze (nazwa, odbiorca, pola, strona) values  ';
     $string='[{"nazwa":"Imi\u0119","typ":"input","placeholder":"Podaj swoje imi\u0119"},  {"nazwa":"Nazwisko","typ":"input","placeholder":"Podaj swoje nazwisko"},{"nazwa":"Wiadomo\u015b\u0107","typ":"textarea","placeholder":"Co chcesz ode mnie :)"},{"nazwa":"Czy masz 18 lat?","typ":"radio","opcje":"Tak\r\nNie"}]';
        $mainArray = json_decode($string,TRUE);




        foreach($mainArray as $count=>$value_array)
            {
                echo '<pre>';

                 $query .= '(';
                foreach($value_array as $key=>$value)
                {
                   //echo $value;
                   //echo "<br>";                      
                   $query .= $value.',';                            

                }
               //echo "<br>";
               $query=rtrim($query,',');
               $query .= '),';

            }


     $query=rtrim($query,',');

       $result = mysql_query($query);
```

?>